# Unable to call external API(POST method) inside dot net core application

Tags: c#, .net-core

I tried inside dot net coer 2.0 application but its always getting 500 internal server error:

Note: 
1. Sometimes getting success, say for example if i hit 10 to 15 times then its gets success one time.

2. The same code I tried in lower version of dot net(Dot net standard) its working fine.

So please help me on this, 
This is my code,

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://xxxxxxxx:xxxx/api/sms/SendSMSVMart");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
//HTTP POST
var postTask = client.PostAsJsonAsync<SMSRequest>("SendSMSVMart", smsRequest).Result;
if (postTask.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
// to do
}
else
{
// to do
}
}
```

Comment: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error comes from the server. So the server doesn't like what you send. I guess, if the code is exactly the same and it works for lower versions, use Fiddler to inspect the differences and potentially log a bug to Microsoft in Github.

Comment: Dear Mike, thanks for your reply, i have identified an issue that when tries in lower versions the request headers going empty like {}  but in the Dot net core 2.0 request headers going like {Transfer-Encoding: chunked}

Answer (score 0):

Finally I resolved this issue using below line

```
 var postTask = client.PostAsync("", new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(smsRequest), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
```